# I have a problem with React Router Dom V6 and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-state

I have a problem with navigation between two routes of same component.

I have a page where there is a form to create and edit user. The routes are:

**/user**

**/user/:id**

But when try navigate from **/user/:id** to **/user** to create new user, the states of component not redeclared. The states come with the same value of page **/user/:id**.
This is occur only when navigate to same component.

See routes:

```
<Route path='user/:id' element={<UserForm />} />
<Route path='user' element={<UserForm />} />
```

The component:

```
const UserForm = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams<FormParams>();
  // const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<MessageProps>();
  const [data, setData] = useState<UserModel>(newData);
  ...
}

export default UserForm;
```

Redirect Function:

```
const newForm = () => {
  try {
    debugger;
    navigate('/user');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
}
```

If I refresh page, the states is redeclared. As it should happen in the redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-router-dom` is optimized to not unnecessarily unmount and remount components.

```
<Route path='user/:id' element={<UserForm />} />
<Route path='user' element={<UserForm />} />
```

When switching between `"/user"` and `"/user/:id"` the `UserForm` component will only get rerendered. The same is true if you navigate from one `"/user/:id"` path to a *different* `"/user/:id"` path. It's clear that `UserForm` has a dependency on this `id` route path parameter. You've a couple options for handling this.

1. Use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `id` route param and rerun/reset any state.

   ```
   const UserForm = () => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     const { id } = useParams<FormParams>();
     // const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
     const [message, setMessage] = useState<MessageProps>();
     const [data, setData] = useState<UserModel>(newData);

     useEffect(() => {
       // reset state or re-issue side-effect based on id param
     }, [id]);
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Add a React key to the `UserForm` component in the route so React ***will*** unmount/mount a new instance when switching between `"/user"` and `"/user/:id"`. Note however that you'd still need a `useEffect` hook to rerun/reset logic/state when staying on the same route and only the `id` changes.

   ```
   <Route path='user/:id' element={<UserForm key="root" />} />
   <Route path='user' element={<UserForm key="id" />} />
   ```